# Merged list of lines not outputting in expected DateTime order

Tags: c#

I am reading in lines of text from many log files and adding them all to a list of lines named lstMerged. What I am now trying to do is output this merged list of lines into one combined file, in order of date and time. My first attempt was to sort the merged list like so:

```
    List<Lines> lstMerged = new List<Lines>();
    foreach (var item in logs)
    {
     lstMerged.AddRange(item.lstLines);//Pass lstLines items in all Logs into a single list lstMerged
    }
    lstMerged.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.DateTime, y.DateTime));
```

This is not working correctly because lines that share the exact same second or millisecond are outputting randomly. For example, if there are 10 lines of text from two different log files with exactly the same date and time, down to the millisecond, those lines are now sorting randomly, i.e. they are not in the order they appear in the original files.

I want all the lines sorted on date and time, but if there are many lines with the same date and time, then I want them to appear in the same order as the original log files. Can anyone see what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: can you provide a small sample of the data in regards to the ones that are outputting randomly can you show the code in reference to the `lstMerged` and how you are adding the items..

Comment: Actually this seems to be the natural way of sorting. you should add an additional parameter to the sort that is the index of the log file or the index of the line inside the log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sort` uses Quicksort algorithm, which is unstable, so items with same values could end up in different positions than original.

[List.Sort Method (Comparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

> This implementation performs an **unstable sort**; that is, **if two
>   elements are equal, their order might not be preserved.** In contrast,
>   a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

Use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which provides stable sorting.

> This method performs a **stable sort**; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved.

```
lstMerged = lstMerged.OrderBy(x=> x.DateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: I had actually tried this: lstMerged.OrderBy(dt => dt.DateTime).ThenBy(dt => DateTime.Parse(dt.DateTime.ToShortTimeString()));  but it returns the logs one after another, rather than all merged together.

Comment: @NepSyn14, I have no idea what you are trying to do with `.ThenBy(dt => DateTime.Parse(dt.DateTime.ToShortTimeString()));`, there is no need, the `OrderBy` on `DateTime` field will sort by `Date` and `Time` component.

Comment: @NepSyn14, use `lstMerged = lstMerged.OrderBy(x=> x.DateTime).ToList();`

Answer (score 5):

You are using `List.Sort()` which uses a Quicksort algorithm that is not stable.

Linq's sorting uses a stable sort algorithm, so you could try using that instead:

```
lstMerged = lstMerged.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: This returns the following error when I build it. Error 2 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @NepSyn14 Try the updated code. It's hard to write the correct code without having access to the actual types. ;)